# How to grab the 2D views/textures from a 3D Object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on a Projection Mapping Project and I am prototyping in Unity 3D. I have a cube like object with a 3D terrain and characters in it.

To recreate the 3D perspective and feel I am using two projectors which will project in a real world object which is exactly like the Unity Object. In order to do this I need to extract 2D views from the shape in Unity.

Is there an easy way to achieve this ?[image][image]

Comment: is it possible you're looking for the RenderTexture features in Unity?  there are masses of tutorials, and it's quite easy.  hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. The image above is kind of what I'm looking to.project onto a real real world object. I will see how I can grab the texture views from each side.

Comment: Leon, it's actually pretty unclear what you're asking *specifically*.  What is the "real world object"?  All you are describing is the texture on a 3D object right?  You can set the texture to anything you want.  It's totally normal to take a photo of a tree and then, obviously, use it as a texture on a tree shape in a 3D engine.  Perhaps you should explain more clearly and specifically what you are trying to do!

Comment: Fattie. I want to design an object in unity say a cube and there's forest inside - a 3d scene. In real world I want to have the physical unity object made. I want the external physical realm object to look like the unity object with the forest inside. I am.not sure how to recreate this effect is real.world with projectors. I was thinking in unity virtual if I grabbed 2d images from each side if I project these in real.world it would look the same.

Comment: I'm afraid your question has nothing to do with computer programming or this site.  You're asking about the state of the art in 3D holographic displays, you can easily google that. Eg, https://lookingglassfactory.com

Answer (score 1):

Interesting project. It sounds like you would need multiple displays, one for each projector, each using a separate virtual camera in Unity, like documented [there](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html).

Not sure if I understood your concept correctly from the description above. If the spectator should be able to walk around the cube, onto which the rendered virtual scene should be projected, it would also be necessary to track a spectator's head/eyes to realize a convincing 3D effect. The virtual scene would need to be rendered from the matching point of view in virtual space (works for only one spectator). Otherwise the perspective would only be "right" from one single point in real space.

The effect would also only be convincing with stereo view, either by using shutter glasses or something similar. Shadows are another problem, when projecting onto the cube from outside the scene. By using only two projectors, you would also need to correct the perspective distortion, when projecting onto multiple sides of cube at the same time.

As an inspiration: There's also this fantastic experiment by Johnny Chung Lee demonstrating a [head tracking technique using the Wii Remote](http://johnnylee.net/projects/wii/), that might be useful in a projection mapping project like yours.

(In order to really solve this problem, it might be best to use AR glasses instead of conventional projectors, which have the projector built in, and use special projection surfaces that allow for multiple spectators at the same time (like [CastAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CastAR)). But I have no idea, if these devices are already on the market... - However, I see the appeal of a simple projection mapping without using special equipment. In that case it might be possible to get away from a realistic 3D scene, and use more experimental/abstract graphics, projected onto the cube...)

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed reply. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project! Projection mapping is fun, there are also lots of interesting things one can do with domes, maybe that's also something worth looking into (http://paulbourke.net/dome/ - lots of good resources on dome projection mapping by Paul Bourke).